# Is it possible to learn math from scratch and how?

Tags: math

I have a quite big development experience and I wonder is it possible to start learning math from scratch. I forgot almost everything I know, even school program. Please give me some guidance on this. Where to start what to do. Are there any math books for developers. May be with exercises to write code or experiment, etc...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let's start with the basics: What *do* you remember? Addition and multiplication at the very least, I hope?

Comment: You should specify what part of mathematics.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Of course I remember all the basics :)

Comment: On a more serious note: retagged because Mathematica is actually a language used to do math, which is pretty different from what you're referring to.

Comment: @NixDev: Then can you be specific about what areas you want to improve on? Geometry? Algebra? Differential or integral calculus? Statistics? Numerology?

Comment: @MartyIX @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : I am mainly interested in Mathematical analysis and vector algebra.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are math books for developers:

- [Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025)
- [Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073229725)

It's hard to say if either one would be a good starting point without knowing what level you're at.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have had high school math, I strongly recommend:

Concrete Mathematics, Second Edition

by Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik (Reading, Massachusetts: Addison-Wesley, 1994), xiii+657pp.
ISBN 0-201-55802-5

Answer (score 1):

I'd review what you should know first (at least a little) before going on to new material.  You'll need a good foundation in algebra, and at least some exposure to calculus before trying  Concrete Mathematics or even The Art of Computer Programming.

If you want to go from the practical side of computing Robert [Sedegwick](http://www.amazon.com/Robert-Sedgewick/e/B000AQ4JCO/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_8?qid=1282336595&sr=1-8), has written some books that have source code explaining computer algorithms and theory.